# Circular Import Error on Model While Querying Within Different Python File in App

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import my journal app model from models.py into prompts.py file within the same journal app to run a function on one of the objects in the journal model. How can I avoid a circular model error with this model import?

My model is set up within the journal app as such in models.py:

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='journal',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    prompt = models.CharField(max_length=256,default=prompt.prompt_gen())
    prompt_html = models.CharField(max_length=256,editable=False,default=prompt.prompt_gen())
    entry = models.TextField(default='What are you thinking about?')
    entry_html = models.TextField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prompt,self.entry

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.prompt_html = misaka.html(self.prompt)
        self.entry_html = misaka.html(self.entry)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('journal:single_entry',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,
                                                'pk':self.pk})
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user','entry']
        verbose_name='entry'
        verbose_name_plural='entries'
```

My prompts.py file within the journal app is set up as such:

```
def prompt_gen():
    from .models import Journal
    journal_str = Journal.objects.raw('SELECT entry FROM journal_Journal')
    qg = TextGenerator(output_type="question")
    prompt = qg.predict([journal_str])
    return prompt
```

I get this error:

```
 File "/Users/-/Desktop/Full_Stack/Projects/My_Django/filter/journal/models.py", line 17, in <module>
    class Journal(models.Model):
  File "/Users/-/Desktop/Full_Stack/Projects/My_Django/filter/journal/models.py", line 20, in Journal
    prompt = models.CharField(max_length=256,default=prompt.prompt_gen())
  File "/Users/-/Desktop/Full_Stack/Projects/My_Django/filter/journal/prompt.py", line 5, in prompt_gen
    from .models import Journal
ImportError: cannot import name 'Journal' from partially initialized module 'journal.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/User
s/-/Desktop/Full_Stack/Projects/My_Django/filter/journal/models.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as it's used for `Journal`, I would suggest moving it into the Class method instead of importing.

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='journal',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    prompt = models.CharField(max_length=256,default=self.prompt_gen())
    prompt_html = models.CharField(max_length=256,editable=False,default=self.prompt_gen())
    entry = models.TextField(default='What are you thinking about?')
    entry_html = models.TextField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prompt,self.entry

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.prompt_html = misaka.html(self.prompt)
        self.entry_html = misaka.html(self.entry)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('journal:single_entry',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,
                                                'pk':self.pk})

    def prompt_gen():
        # why not to use Django ORM here?
        journal_str = Journal.objects.raw('SELECT entry FROM journal_Journal')
        qg = TextGenerator(output_type="question")
        prompt = qg.predict([journal_str])
        return prompt

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user','entry']
        verbose_name='entry'
        verbose_name_plural='entries'
```

Answer (score 0):

`default` can be function to be called rather than the result of calling the function

```
prompt = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=prompt.prompt_gen)
```

If you use the method of passing the `default` argument then the function won't be called before the model is fully initialized